# Testing pundit for create action with a third parameter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pundit

The problem in testing a create action is that the object is not already created.  Thus a class policy initialisation could state:

```
def initialize(user, promotion)
  @user = user
  @promotion = promotion
end
```

with  `@shop = @promotion.shop_id` added to the edit/update/delete policy actions.

However, the user may have a role within that shop that allows it to do some privileged actions, such as `create` ...

```
def shopmanager 
  @roleshopuser ||= Roleshopuser.where(['user_id = ? AND shop_id = ? AND role_id IN (?)', user.id, @shop, [1,2]]).first
end
```

*note: this functions properly on edit/update/destroy actions, thus validating the testing fixtures*

As the initialisation process indicates, the promotion requires a shop_id and is thus a submitted param to the create action.  Therefore the controller action is defined as (with the puts confirming the presence of the parameter):

```
def create
  puts params[:promotion][:shop_id]
  @target_shop = params[:promotion][:shop_id]
  @promotion = Promotion.new(promotion_params)
  authorize @promotion
```

and the policy adapted accordingly

```
  def create?
    @shop = @target_shop
puts user.id
puts user.admin?
puts shopmanager.nil?
    !user.nil? && (user.admin? || !shopmanager.nil?)
  end
```

*again the `puts` do indicate that there is proper handling of the attributes and method*

The test however fails

```
  test "should create promotion" do
    @shop = shops(:three_4)
    @shopusers.each do |user|
      sign_in user
      @shopusers.each do |user|
        sign_in user
        assert_difference('Promotion.count') do
post promotions_url, params: { promotion: { name: (@promotion.name + user.id.to_s), shop_id: @promotion.shop_id [...]
        end
  
        assert_redirected_to promotion_url(Promotion.last)
      end
      sign_out user
    end
  end
```

From the `puts` data, the policy runs on `user.admin?`, but the policy fails where `true` is returned for the next user fixture when running method `shopmanager.nil?` (admin is false).  As the edit/update functions work with the same fixtures, this points to an error in the policy for `create`.

What is it?

Answer (score 0):

There is a path through this [as indicated in documentation](https://github.com/varvet/pundit#additional-context).

For the above case, the initialization requires modification to handle additional elements

```
  attr_reader :user, :promotion, :shop

  def initialize(context, promotion)
    @user = context.user
    @shop = context.shop
    @promotion = promotion
  end
```

the Class-specific controller needs amending to pass on the context, adjusted for whether the object already exists or not.

```
class PromotionsController < ApplicationController
  include Pundit
  private
  
    def pundit_user
      if @promotion.blank?
        shop = params[:promotion][:shop_id]
      else
        shop = @promotion.shop_id
      end
      CurrentContext.new(current_user, shop)
    end
```

Then the policy can check if the user is a manager of the shop.